# How to automatically open and close an .xlsm file

Tags: python, excel, linux, windows

I have `generate.xlsm` file. When I open it in Windows manually, the `report.csv` file is updated. 
I need to open and close `generate.xlsm` every day. I tried to open it with python both in Linux and in Windows using the following:

```
f= open(filename) 
f.close()
```

and the following:

```
import openpyxl    
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
book.close()
```

but neither of them updates the `report.csv` file.
So I would like to know if there is a way to open and close an .xlsm file or maybe it is possible to schedule a task in Windows that not only opens but also closes the file.

Comment: While you are opening the generate.xlsm file from windows manually, why is the report.csv getting updated. Can you please specify with some example what exactly is happening

Comment: considering that there is some kind of macro running up on opening the xlsm, i suppose it needs to be saved. add `book.save()` and try if that works.

Comment: When I open `generate.xlsm` file, it reads 3 other files then it generates and saves the `report.csv`. Note that I don't need to save `generate.xlsm` file.

Comment: What is *"it"*? A document doesn't create anything, unlike code.

Comment: Generate.xlsm opens the report.csv, deletes all the data in report.csv, rewrites new data, saves and closes the report.csv.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand the crucial point here: *generate.xlsm* is a document. It doesn't do anything. Applications (such as Excel), on the other hand, can execute code. If you fail to understand this distinction you won't be able to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could open and close the .xlsm file by creating a `.vbs` file. I used the following question and solution:
[How to close excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979154/how-to-close-excel-file-from-vbscript-without-being-prompted). 
Then I scheduled a task for the .vbs file in Windows.