# How to close Excel file from VBS script?

Tags: excel, vbscript, exit, excel-2016

The is a VBS file started by cscript.exe from task planner. The script look fine and should close the excel file after the macro has done. However, the excel file stay in windows background and does not close. The macro from Excel run and save a copy of itself itself and activeworkbook.close and send an email with the new file then vbs should close the excel application. Everything work great except the both Excel file stay in the background. Any way to force to close these file and not all excel process??

Question: Terminate and kill the excel file from background

Using Excel 2016, .VBS script as per below:

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\order1.xlsm")
ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set objFileName = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing

WScript.Sleep 3000

Set ObjExcel2 = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWB2 = ObjExcel2.Workbooks.Open("C:\order2.xlsm")
ObjWB2.Close False
ObjExcel2.Quit
Set objFileName2 = Nothing
Set ObjExcel2 = Nothing
```

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979154/how-to-close-excel-file-from-vbscript-without-being-prompted/20979612 (and [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbscript+quit+excel))

Comment: If you want to get a handle on what's going wrong, making the created Excel instance visible is a good step to take.

Comment: Not a duplicate because it involve more than 1 process. The VOODOO code from post ashleedawg shared is working for 1 process but not for multiple process into same vbs call with excel containing macro. GetObject solved this issue and only require 2 things. Getobject and close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open up excel and get workbook without using CreateObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25151080) (Seen as though the question you ask isn't [what you are trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963089/how-to-close-excel-file-from-vbs-script#comment125467207_70966799)).

Answer (score -3):

Here is your code

```
Set ObjWB = GetObject("C:\order1.xlsm")
```

Note all your other lines are unnecessary.

The reason you have problems is that you write **vodoo code**. Note all your copied voodoo code is the same as the one line above. But note code was meant to be written as I have. You are closing files then setting a no longer existent object to nothing.

Comment: Complete nonsensical rambling but by testing it with multiple call from vbs it works! I will never understand why people here are fast on closing post and telling similar question have a solution while the current problem on the post is not the same because it involve more than 1 process. Anyway, Ill keep away from VODOO code that people here forward as a solution. Thanks community and KL

Comment: "You are closing files then setting a no longer existent object to nothing." That's called manually clearing the memory. Useful in long-running scripts, but VBScript does tidy up its own variables at the end of execution so not always relevant.

Comment: @John your question "Question: Terminate and kill the excel file from background" is not what this code does, it simply opens the [automation object associated with that file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/kdccchxa(v=vs.84)).